# Preventing a wrong-way git merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-flow, git-config

Right now at work, we have different git branches for different versions of our product. For example: branches called v1.0, v2.0, v3.0 and a master branch.

Different customers run different versions, but new features are only merged into the latest version branch and the master branch. Bugfixes however, are still merged in on lower version branches. Let’s say a bug was found on v1.0, then our current git workflow is:

1. to make a feature branch from v1.0,
2. make the fix
3. Merge back into v1.0 and push
4. Merge v1.0 into v2.0 and push
5. Merge v2.0 into v3.0 and push
6. Merge v3.0 into master and push

This causes bugfixes found on lower versions to be included in all versions upwards of the product.

V3.0 would thus contain all commits that v2.0 contains, plus additional feature commits made on version v3.0. Master would contain all commits that v3.0 contains, plus additional feature commits for the future release of the product etc.

Now we've had a few times where people made the merge the wrong way, downwards instead of upwards. So they merged v3.0 into v2.0 for example. This causes huge problems in the sense that whenever there is a new bugfix release of the product for customers on v2.0 of the software, they would actually get v3.0.

It’s actually quite easy to do these merges the wrong way, but the consequences can be quite big especially if the wrong merge stays undetected for a long time.

Is  there any way to prevent people from merging downwards in the version branches, and only upwards? (So from v1.0 to v2.0 etc.).

I should mention that we cannot define any custom git-hooks on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* one way that is completely reliable, which you have completely ruled out:

> I should mention that we cannot define any custom git-hooks on the server side.

Without this, all you have are unreliable depends-on-each-user methods.

Each user can install his or own hooks.  You could set up pre-push hooks that check to make sure you are not doing something you would not like.  If each user does this, and provided that each user also does not bypass the hooks, that would prevent pushes that would do something you do not like.

Writing hooks is not all that easy, and of course, if someone fails to install the hook, or installs it incorrectly, or bypasses it, it will have no effect.  But it is available.

(There's no pre-merge hook, though there is a post-merge hook.  This is why I suggested the pre-push hook.)